Mobx Lazy+Cached
Just on a basic example from the docs
class OrderLine {
    price = 0
    amount = 1

    constructor(price) {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
        this.price = price
    }

    get total() {
        console.log("Computing...")
        return this.price * this.amount
    }
}


The total becomes cached only once autorun is called accessing total property.
Still how to make total really both Cached and Lazy since there're heavy calculations suspected. So that it is a matter for them to take a place only once the first real reference (read) is occurred. Instead autorun makes this exact effect in advance (by design)
So ho to do something like
const makeAutoObservableLazyCached = (target) => {
  makeAutoObservable(target)
  // ...whatever makes all(or maybe selectively decorated?) the computed props become cached without reading the value? 
}


Turns out this is a complex case. In my opinion it would be better to rewrite the getters instead of using the solution I will provide with the code below because it might be hard to debug (depends):
import { observer, useLocalObservable } from 'mobx-react';
import { autorun, runInAction, makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx';

const listGetters = (instance) => {
  return Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(instance)))
    .filter((e) => typeof e[1].get === 'function' && e[0] !== '__proto__')
    .map((e) => e[0]);
};

class OrderLine {
  price = 0;
  amount = 1;

  constructor(price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  get total() {
    return this.price * this.amount;
  }
}

const makeAutoObservableLazyCached = (target) => {
  // ...whatever makes all(or maybe selectively decorated?) the computed props become cached without reading the value?
  const getters = listGetters(target);
  getters.forEach((getter) => {
    const getterBody = target.__lookupGetter__(getter).toString();
    const body = getterBody.slice(getterBody.indexOf('{') + 1, getterBody.lastIndexOf('}'));
    Object.defineProperty(target, `_get${getter}`, {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: Function(body)
    });
    Object.defineProperty(target, getter, {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: target[`_get${getter}`]() // set me to null if you don't one initial calculation
    });
  });
  makeAutoObservable(target);
  getters.forEach((getter) => {
    autorun(() => {
      console.log('autorun');
      // find a way to prevent initial reaction if you want initial calculation but prevent autorun to fire after it
      target[getter] = target[`_get${getter}`]();
    });
  });

  return target;
};

const App = observer(({ price = 5 }) => {
  const state = useLocalObservable(() => ({
    orderLine: makeAutoObservableLazyCached(new OrderLine(price)),
    changePrice: (value) => {
      runInAction(() => {
        state.orderLine.price = value;
      });
    },
    changeAmount: (value) => {
      runInAction(() => {
        state.orderLine.amount = value;
      });
    }
  }));

  console.log(state.orderLine);
  console.log(state.orderLine.total);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => state.changePrice(2)}>change price 2</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => state.changeAmount(3)}>change amount 3</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
});

export default App;

To make it work with specific getters rewrite like so:
const makeAutoObservableLazyCached = (target = {}, selectedGetters = []) => {
  // ...whatever makes all(or maybe selectively decorated?) the computed props become cached without reading the value?
  const getters = selectedGetters?.length ? selectedGetters : listGetters(target);

and
orderLine: makeAutoObservableLazyCached(new OrderLine(price), ['total'])

